# Permutation group and element of order equal $15$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

$\newcommand{\ord}{\operatorname{ord}}$
I need to settle this question:

> Does there exist a $\sigma \in S_{10}$ such that $\,\ord(\sigma) = 15\,$ ?

---

Suppose that $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ are disjoint cycles. We have $\ord(\sigma_1 \sigma_2) = \operatorname{lcm}(\ord(\sigma_1),\ord(\sigma_2))$.

Let $\sigma_1=(1,2,3)$ and $\sigma_2=(4,5,6,7,8)$. Of course $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in S_{10}$ and $\ord(\sigma_1) = 3$, $\ord(\sigma_2) = 5$.

Let $ \sigma = \sigma_1 \sigma_2$. Hence we have $\ord(\sigma) = \operatorname{lcm}(3,5) = 15$.

So the answer is yes, there exists a $\sigma \in S_{10}$ such that $\ord(\sigma) = 15$.

Is this true?

Comment: Your proof is good, except you should have LCM where you have GCD.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\ord}{\operatorname{ord}}$

Yes, it is true, and your proof is just fine, *save for* the fact that $$\ord\,(\phi_1\phi_2) = \operatorname{lcm}\,(\ord\,(\phi_1), \ord\,(\phi_2))$$

where $\,\operatorname{lcm}\,(\alpha, \beta)$ denotes the *least common multiple* of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Via computational approach, you can see how many elements are there in the group of order $15$. This is a GAP's small program.

```
> S10:=SymmetricGroup(IsPermGroup,10);;
> f:=Filtered(Elements(S10),t->Order(t)=15);;
> Size(f);
[ 120960
```

Comment: Actually, one need not to generate the list of all elements to do this. The order of an element is an invariant of a conjugacy class, and (especially in this case) classes are well known. So one could use `List(ConjugacyClasses(SymmetricGroup(10)),c->Order(Representative(c)))` or even avoid constructing the group itself with `OrdersClassRepresentatives(CharacterTable("S10"))`

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Thanks for your complete hint and the answer. What I tried is wrong. In fact, my GAP seemed not work properly when I called $S_{10}$ or $S_{15}$. And that is why I thought may be I did something wrong in typing or calling the codes. I made that question and after you did comment, I tried again slowly and see that the GAP is my friend again. Thanks for your time.

Comment: $+1_++^{+^+}\quad$